# How to pass data to header without reload using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 headers. Header 2 is loaded at the bottom of header 1. Header 1 consist of navigation tabs. I want to display upon clicking on `#navbar > li > a`
I want it to capture the text and pass it to header 2. But header 2 doesn't seem to reload since it is header thus data is not received I guess. How to pass data to header 2 and ask header 2 update value of `$PageTitle`.

**header.php**

```
<?php
$DefaultWebsiteTitle = "Planetarium Negara";
$WebsiteTitle = '';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
    <?php
        if(isset($WebsiteTitle) && !empty($WebsiteTitle)){
            echo $WebsiteTitle;
        }
        else{
            echo $DefaultWebsiteTitle;
        }
    ?>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap\bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js\bootstrap\bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js\jquery\jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <!-- Brand/logo -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="image\planetarium_logo.jpg" alt="logo" 
style="width:50px; height:50px;">
        </a>

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul id="navbar" class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="TicketSale">Ticket Sale</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="TicketClaim">Ticket Claim</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="TicketRefund">Ticket Refund</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="CustomerSurvey">Customer Survey</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<?php include('header2.php');?>
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
```

**header2.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['PageTitle']);
$PageTitle = $_POST['PageTitle'];
$DefaultPageTitle = 'Planetarium Negara'
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <?php
                if(isset($PageTitle)&&!empty($PageTitle)){
                    echo $PageTitle;
                }else{
                    echo $DefaultPageTitle;
                }
            ?>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            time
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            logout
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**header.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').load('TicketClaim.php');
});

$('#navbar > li > a').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page+".php");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: is this `$('#content').load('TicketClaim.php');` code work fine??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Yes, it works fine

Comment: so I think your `var page = $(this).attr('href');` is not correct .. not the code but the attribute .. so you need to provide more code about `#navbar > a` href attribute

Comment: Basically, You just want to change the content of the div that initially contains the title, no?

Comment: @Skaparate Yes exactly, i try search in stackoverflow but most of them no reply or explaination. I have updated my code

Comment: Any reason you can't use a html form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your point .. you can use `.load()` to pass a values to php but while you're using `$PageTitle = $_POST['PageTitle'];` so you can use `.post()` method .. see the next code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // try it directly onload
     $.post("TicketClaim.php" , {PageTitle : 'This Is The New Title'} , function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
     });

     $('#navbar > li > a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent redirect 
        var page = $(this).attr('href').trim();  // get the page name
        var pagetitle = $(this).text(); // change this line with the title you want. I don't know from where you got the titles but here I just assumes thats the text of the anchor
        $.post(page+".php" , {PageTitle : pagetitle} , function(data){
           $('#content').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: look @KIRPALSINGH I don't know what is exactly not work .. but I'm sure my code is 100% right .. you may need to see updated answer

Comment: If you notice in header2.php .. even if you send a POST request, the value is not received by PHP. But instead you directly manipulate UI to display the value. I want the value to be send as POST and received by var_dump($_POST['PageTitle']);

Comment: your code doesnt send the data as i cant receive it via $_POST['PageTitle'];

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH my code will send `PaeTitle` to `TicketClaim.php` onload .. if you want to send to `header2.php` change `TicketClaim.php` to `header2.php`

Comment: Yes, i guess i had to replace my include('header2.php') from header to individual files to receive the post value. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the text node of the div that initially contains the title. To do that, just add an id to the "Page Title" div and then use jQuery to change it:

```
<!-- Content omitted -->
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="page-title">
Initial Title <!-- This is set by PHP initially -->
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#navbar > li > a').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var text = $(this).text();
    // Here the text is changed before the page load
    // $('#page-title').html(text);
    $('#content').load(page+".php", function() {
      // The text is changed after the page is loaded.
      $('#page-title').html(text);
    });
    return false;
});
```